# phantomjs failing to parse date correctly

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

I have the following code that parses a string to a date, and then check if it is valid or not.

```
var initial = new Date(initialDate);
if (initial.toString() === "Invalid Date") {
    return false;
} else { 
         // do something;
}
```

I give for example `initialDate = "11-11-2016";` and still my tests fail saying that I have a falsy value. On the other hand, running the same **Expect** with **Jasmine** works just fine.

Comment: `11-11-2016` is not a useful date representation. Use ISO 8601.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format

Comment: As per the reference, mentioned date is `Invalid Date`, Pass the date in __`YYYY-MM-DD`__ format..

Comment: Thanks guys, it was indeed that.